# Multidimensional Array in Liberty Basic

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a newbie learning programming and the book I'm using is using Liberty Basic.
The book gives the code example below for a two-dimensional array.

```
dim victim$(2, 3)

for i = 1 to 2
    for j = 1 to 3
        prompt "Who do you want to hurt?"; enemy$
        victim$(i, j) = enemy$
    next j
next i

prompt "Type x location of the array item that you want to print, such as 1:"; x
prompt "Type y location ot the array item that you want to print, such as 1:"; y
print victim$(x, y) + " deserves to be hurt the most."

end
```

But when I run this example using Liberty Basic v4.04 I recieve a syntax error on this line of code:

```
dim victim$(2, 3)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

Answer:

```
dim victim$(2, 3)
for i = 1 to 2
    for j = 1 to 3
        prompt "Who do you want to hurt?"; enemy$
        victim$(i, j) = enemy$
    next j
next i
prompt "Type x location of the array item that you want to print, such as 1:"; x
prompt "Type y location ot the array item that you want to print, such as 1:"; y
print victim$(x, y) + " deserves to be hurt the most."
end
```

Once I removed the extra blank lines the code worked.